# ggplot change size of some legend items

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with two legends, one for point colour and one for linetype.

I would like to extend the width of *only* the linetype legend key.

I can set the overall `legend.key.width` with `theme(legend.key.width = unit(5, "cm"))`, but this increases the width for both legends. Is there a way to set the width for just one of the legends?

Example

```
iris$Group <- as.factor(rep(1:3, 50))

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify options for each legend type independently by `guides()` function:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group)) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(5, 'cm')))
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me it only works under `theme(legend.key.width = unit(5,"cm"))`